# In SOAP MTOM, what is the syntax to specify "content-id" in Attachment Part section?

Tags: java, soap, saaj

On this http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/mtom-guide.html#MTOM_Backward_Compatibility_with_SwA link, the "content-id" is specified in angular brackets. 
--MIMEBoundary4A7AE55984E7438034 
content-type: application/octet-stream 
content-transfer-encoding: binary 
**content-id: <1.A91D6D2E3D7AC4D580@apache.org>** 

In XOP element in SOAP Part, it is referred as - 
< xop:Include **href="cid:1.A91D6D2E3D7AC4D580@apache.org"** 
                        xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" >


(No angular brackets here )

 I don't see anywhere that the angular brackets are mandetory.
I am using SAAJ APIs and it seems they don't attach any brackets to the content id provided.

Can anyone put some more focus on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is specified in RFC 2392:

> A "cid" URL is converted to the corresponding Content-ID message header by removing the "cid:" prefix, converting the % encoded character to their equivalent US-ASCII characters, and enclosing the remaining parts with an angle bracket pair, "<" and ">".

Some SwA/MTOM implementations don't conform to that spec and don't add the brackets. This is generally not a problem because most SwA/MTOM implementations accept such non conforming messages.

Regarding SAAJ, the Javadoc of the `AttachmentPart#setContentId(String)` method specifies this:

> Sets the MIME header whose name is "Content-Id" with the given value.

This means that you should pass it a value that includes the brackets.

Comment: Thanks. My apllication uses SAAJ APIs internally. So is it SAAJ APis role to put the cid value in angular brackets? or my application which adds or fetches the attachments from the soap message should explicitly do it ? 
.
Or in other words, if SAAJ APIs are not doing it, then I should not care much about it ?